# General Rule for When to Implement IDisposable

Tags: .net, design-patterns

**EDIT:** This question is a duplicate of [What is the difference between managed and native resources when disposing? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492984/what-is-the-difference-between-managed-and-native-resources-when-disposing-ne) and many others. Please answer the others if you have something to add.

---

According to the *Framework Design Guidelines* by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams, a type that contains instances of disposable types should implement IDisposable.

Is there any other general rule of thumb for when it is best practice to implement IDisposable?

Comment: This is a multiple, mega-duplicate. Please do a couple minute's search of SO first.

Comment: I don't agree this is a duplicate of "What is the diff.." because the previous question doesn't really speak to best practice or containing fields that implement IDisposable.

Comment: I'm sure it's a duplicate of something but I don't think it's an exact duplicate of the question linked above.

Comment: @John Saunders: My apologies.  I actually did do a search before posting my question and didn't find a question that was asked that I felt was a duplicate--my failing in searching.  I was following logic I found over at meta.stackoverflow.com: "There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds our fellow programmers can find the answer they’re looking for."

Comment: Another MSDN resource that's useful in this instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172%28v=vs.80%29.aspx - The related rules are also applicable in response to the original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between managed and native resources when disposing? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492984/what-is-the-difference-between-managed-and-native-resources-when-disposing-ne)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implement IDisposable when you have a class what wraps an unmanaged resource or when your class has a field that implements IDisposable.

Answer (score 5):

When you need to [release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) unmanaged resources, implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

Comment: You should also implement IDisposable if your class has fields that implement IDisposable

Comment: The initial question states "is there any other general rule of thumb for when it is best practice to implement IDispoable" in addition to the rule that a type containing instances of disposable types should implement IDisposable.

Comment: Further, if you have instances of objects that implement IDispoable, then you have unmanaged resources that need to be released and thus it falls under the rule I stated.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

> Use the Dispose method of this interface to explicitly release unmanaged resources in conjunction with the garbage collector. The consumer of an object can call this method when the object is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you alocate resources that must be released, such as files, handles, etc. For example, if you are using Win32 resources (which do not implement IDisposable) you should implement IDisposable to release them.

Answer (score 1):

I normally implement IDisposable every time I need to do a clean up of items. For me this is when writing code that abstracts database/network/filesystems.

It just marks items ready for the Garbage Collector instead of waiting for it to try do it on its own.

Answer (score 1):

IDisposable is one of a programmers main weapons against .Net memory leaks.  Whilst the documentation suggests that it should be used for external resources, I make extensive use of IDisposable to release **internal** resources such as pointers to parent classes.

It is quite easy to demonstrate the requirement by creating two mutually referential classes i.e. foo and bar. foo refers to bar and vice versa.  When foo falls out of scope, the GC sees bar still refers to it so it is not collected (and vice versa). The memory is not collected.

This is the same style of problem exhibited by EventHandlers where the reference is not released when the form is closed unless it is explicitly released or the WeakEvent model is implemented.

I would suggest that best practice is to assume a C++ programming model where you clean up after yourself using Dispose **unless** you are convinced that the GC can work it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the class is responsible for the *lifetime* of an `IDisposable`-object then it should implement the `IDisposable` interface and dispose of it (or use the `using` statement).  This is because dependency injection containers will be very unhappy with you if you start disposing of the singletons they have created.