# Where to close a TcpClient member

Tags: c#, tcp, destructor, idisposable

**Context:** I have a class that implements a "Session", maintaining a TCP connection to a server during it's lifetime. In the constructor, I create a TcpClient instance with a given IP address and port of a server to connect to.

```
   public Session(IPAddress ipAddress)
   {
       Client = new TcpClient(ipAddress.ToString(), 1234); //create a client to a server which we will later use to work with
       DataStream = Client.GetStream(); //get the stream for later usage
   }
```

Objects of this session will occasionally send and receive data to and from their associated server.

My question now is: **Where should I close the TcpClient and its underlying NetworkStream?**

**Should I implement IDisposable?** But What happens if the user of my class forgets to call Dispose?

**Should I implement a Destructor (aka Finalizer)?** But AFAIK I should never access managed resources from there?

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @abatishchev: While I like to take advice, I can not follow the intention of your edits. I find, that code formatting and emphasis of important parts of the question helpful. Also the title mentioning the "member" quality of the TcpClient meant too distinguish the questions from others, especially to avoid recommendations to use "using". Please explain your intentions with the edit to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I implement IDisposable?

Yes

> But What happens if the user of my class forgets to call Dispose?

you should follow the Disposable pattern as defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that hint. What disturbs me, that there is always the notion of "unmanaged" resources. What should I do with my TcpClient. To me this is a managed resource. Can I treat it as "unmanaged" with regard to disposing and call close in the Dispose method?

Comment: Everything in .NET which implements `IDisposable` (well, almost everything) has unmanaged resources. Hence the need to dispose .NET classes which implements `IDisposable`. You could of course let the GC take care of the `TcpClient` (when it feels like it), but I prefer to release the resources as soon as I'm done with them.

Comment: So there is no need for a finalizer when wrapping .NET classes, but using Disposable pattern (but without the finializer) allows your users to free the resources directly.

Answer (score 1):

See the myriad topics on "[When should I Implment IDisposable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125693/general-rule-for-when-to-implement-idisposable)"

The trigger for you, being that you have a field (`Client`) which implements IDisposable. Thus, your class should be Disposable.

Answer (score 0):

Very few classes should have cleanup finalizers.  If the code which is responsible for managing an `IDisposable` instance neglects to call `IDisposable.Dispose` before abandoning it, the code should be fixed.  Adding a finalizer might mask the problem, but won't solve it, and will very likely introduce Heisenbugs™.  Further, if a class is responsible for things which implement `IDisposable` and have finalizers, the class will need to ensure that those things' `Dispose` method gets called (likely from its own `Dispose` method), but will not be responsible for calling those things' finalizers from its own.  Indeed, when a class' finalizer is running, one of the following three things will usually be true about any finalizable objects to which it holds a reference:

1. It will already have been finalized.

   It will already be in a queue to be finalized soon after the present finalizer is done.

   A live reference to it will exist somewhere else, and it shouldn't be cleaned up yet.

In any of those cases, the proper thing for the finalizer to do with the object is "nothing".

Comment: I agree, that with the "should be fixed". But I am developing a library to be used by others, and I want to make sure, that my library does not introduce resource leaks, even when the other user of my code is a sloppy programmer.

Comment: @Marcel: Finalizers introduce a lot of tricky issues that are very hard to get right.  Further, even when written perfectly, they will frequently turn code which would fail in a clear and obvious way into code which will work 99% of the time but may fail in bizarre and obscure ways.  For example, if an object holds a resource in field `r`, the last thing one of the object's methods does is use that resource, and the last surviving reference to the object is abandoned immediately after calling that method, the finalizer could get triggered *while that resource is still in use*.

Comment: @Marcel: If your client uses `Dispose` properly, then the above problem can't occur, since abandoning the last surviving reference while calling some method other than `Dispose` would imply the client wasn't going to call `Dispose`.  On the other hand, if the client uses `Dispose` properly, the finalizer will be irrelevant.  While there are some occasions where one cannot reasonably expect a client to `Dispose` useless objects, in most cases debugging client code will be easier if `Dispose`d objects are left hanging than if finalizers try to fix them.