# IDisposable Field

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, garbage-collection, idisposable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General Rule for When to Implement IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125693/general-rule-for-when-to-implement-idisposable)

I'm looking for the right approach of releasing a disposable object. In this case `obj1` has the method `Close()` above and beyond `Dispose()` one.

```
  class Test{
      private DisposableObject1 obj1;
      public void Method1(){
        //creating obj1
      }

      public void Method2(){
        //using obj1
      }

       public void Method3(){
        //releasing obj1
        obj1.Close();
        obj1.Dispose();
        obj1 = null;
      }

    }
```

So is the approach above (`Method3()`) the right one to dispose the `obj1`?
Pay attention that it's used in many methods, that is `using` isn't the right approach.

Comment: The Using statement is the preferred way; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx. For example, if your object was a SqlConnection (which implments IDisposable) Close is called as part of Dispose.

Comment: I'm actually going to try to delete my answer. It's already covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125693/general-rule-for-when-to-implement-idisposable and I should really have done some searching before jumping in :-)