# Destroy object passed ByRef to a form when i Close it VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have an MDI container with some child forms.

All the child forms receive an object from the main in this way.

```
Public Sub New(ByRef obj As myClass)
    Me.myObj = obj
End Sub
```

Now i close the child form like this:

```
Private Sub btnCloseModule_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCloseModule.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

but it keeps alive the object passed and all the forms opened by the child form.

When i close one of this child i would like to destroy also the object that i receive. How can I do that?

My idea is that when you close the child form, you remove all stuff related to it. It would be great also to close all the forms opened by the child form.

Thanks

Comment: Try `myObj=Nothing` or `myObj.Dispose` before closing the form

Comment: it says Dispose is not a member of myObj

Comment: what about `myObj = Nothing`

Comment: `myObj = Nothing` doesn't really dispose of it, though, it just dereference it. It'll still be alive for a while until the garbage collector gets it, so if the object catch or emit events , it's still going to do it's thing until then. Worse, if it's referenced elsewhere, it just won't disappear.

Comment: is what i want to avoid

Comment: The `myClass` should implement the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netcore-3.1#examples) interface to clean up it's disposable objects, then you can call `myObj.Dispose()` in the Form's close event. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19097700/10216583) for example. And what is the business of the `ByRef` here? I don't think you need it here.

Comment: Are you sure you need to destroy it?  One of the biggest features of .NET is the garbage collector; unless there are specific cleanup functions that need to run, you shouldn't try to destroy things yourself, you should just let the GC do its job.  If there are specific cleanup functions that need to run, then you need to implement `IDisposable` as noted in the previous comment.

Comment: Ummm... I would expect exactly that when you're passing the object in byRef.  If you want the child form to manage it's state, shouldn't you be passing that variable in ByVal?

Comment: Why is that parameter declared `ByRef` in the first place? There is no justification for it. Declare it `ByVal`.

Comment: When the parameter is a reference type (class) then the ONLY reason to declare it `ByRef` is if you want to assign something to the parameter inside the method and have that change reflected in the original variable. When the parameter is a value type (structure) then you would also declare it `ByRef` if you want to set a field or property of the parameter and have that change reflected in the original variable. NEVER do either in a constructor. This is not VB6. Reference type objects aren't copied by default, which is the whole point, and value types shouldn't be big enough for it to matter.