# How do you dispose a local SqlConnection?

Tags: vb.net, dispose, sqlconnection

Im programming in vb.net

I want to read data from an mssql database. I want to make it flexible for several different queries, so I put the connecting part into a separate class. Whenever I want to make a query I can get with it a preconfigured DataAdapter.
But because of this separation I dont know how to correctly dispose my SqlConnection after collecting the data.

An examplatory use:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim DBA As New DBAccess("dummycommand")
        DBA.provideAdapter.Fill(dummytable)
        ...Dispose? 'This is the part where you usually dispose your datacollecting ressources
    End Sub
End Class

Friend Class DBAccess
    Private SqlString As String

    Friend Sub New(ByVal sql As String)
        SqlString = sql
    End Sub

    Friend Function provideAdapter() As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection("dummyconstring")
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, cn)
        Return da
    End Function
End Class
```

Can you tell me how I change this concept to fit a dispose?

Comment: Yuo could add a `Dispose` method to your `DBAccess` class. Does [Dispose class vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097555/dispose-class-vb-net) help?

Comment: I don't want to take away your enthusiasm, but at this point in the evolution of programming techniques, I think it is best to dedicate your time to study an ORM

Comment: Since you're not actually using the DataAdapter for anything useful (to build Commands and other stuff), you could make your method return a DataTable instead and declare the Connection object with a `Using` statement. You can then load the DataTable using its `Load()` method, passing in a DataReader (which you also need to dispose in the same way).

Comment: @Steve on the contrary once he understands ORM you may add to his enthusiasm!

Comment: @Jimi To let the method return a datatable, I would need to make this datatable in the first place, which I would do with a DataAdapter as well as I dont know the correct method I suppose. I will look up ORM, maybe its redundant at that point anyways

Comment: ?? You would have `dummytable = [DBAccess].GetTable()` and you of course don't need a DataAdapter at all to fill a DataTable, you can load a DataTable from a DataReader. You use a DataAdapter when you need that object to perform Update / Insert etc. commands, not to simply load the data and then dispose of it. Just a waste.

Comment: Thanks i didnt have a clueue. So DataAdapter is more for writing than Reading? They should call it DataUpdater. :)

Comment: @autoque I use EntityFramework whenever I must query a database, no matter how small the project. The code is just much, much neater and you get strongly-typed results from queries which EF will generate for you when you build your model. You can selectively add tables in a graphical editor and it's just so simple. It doesn't matter if one is redundant, what matters is which is best suited for the application and IMO EF wins 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your data access class Disposable

```vb
Friend Class DBAccess
    Implements IDisposable

    Private ReadOnly sqlString As String
    Private disposedValue As Boolean
    Private cn As SqlConnection
    Private da As SqlDataAdapter

    Friend Sub New(sql As String)
        sqlString = sql
    End Sub

    Friend Function provideAdapter() As SqlDataAdapter
        cn = If(cn, New SqlConnection("dummyconstring"))
        da = If(da, New SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, cn))
        Return da
    End Function

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                da?.Dispose()
                cn?.Dispose()
            End If
            disposedValue = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(disposing:=True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

and use it like this

```vb
Using DBA As New DBAccess("dummycommand")
    DBA.provideAdapter.Fill(dummytable)
End Using ' Will automatically call Dispose here
```

but in the long run you could look at an ORM such as Entity Framework to make your life easier.