# Cancel the Initialization of a UserControl or Dispose it in the constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, constructor, user-controls, caliburn.micro

I'm creating an UserControl dialog inside an WPF application.
Here is its constructor:

```
public ExcelExportView()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  // some stuffs here.
  // IsCancelled may got the value true/false

  if (IsCancelled)
  {
    // is there anyway to dispose the UserControl here?
  }
}
```

Here I'm using `Caliburn.Micro` to bootstrap my app and creating Views.

So the question is: **Is there anyway to dispose the UserControl in the middle of constructing it?**

Answer (score 1):

`Dispose` method is just another method. You can call it at anytime, from anywhere. In fact, you should call it for any disposable instances that available before you let them to go out of scope.

It depends on what you want to Dispose at this stage of the constructor. If you have any Disposable objects initialized you can Dispose them. Check if they are not null first..

Having said that, this code/design doesn't smells good for me.

**Edit**

UserControl is not Disposable by default because there are no any diposable objects. Implement IDisposable when you have a class what wraps an unmanaged resource or when your class has a field that implements IDisposable.

Comment: How do I call that method? There's no `Dispose()` here.

Comment: @Envil: Sure, because you haven't implemented IDisposable in your UserControl. UserControl is not Disposable by default because there are no any diposable objects. Have a look at this for "When to implement IDisposable" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125693/general-rule-for-when-to-implement-idisposable

Comment: Thank you, I've learned something. But actually, after implementing IDisposable interface, the Dialog still shows up. I have found my design flaw so that I don't need to call the Dispose like that. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Envil: Great that you have learned about IDisposable. If you don't have any Disposable objects, event subscriptions or unmanaged resources there is nothing to Dispose.