# BMS_DAL.BMSDataContext type used in using statement must be implicitly convertible to "System.IDisposable

Tags: c#

I have this error in C# program

```
public bool Delete(ref ENTValidationErrors validationErrors, int userAccountId)
     {
         if (DBAction == DBActionEnum.Delete)
         {
             // Begin database transaction
             using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
             {
                 // Create data context
                 using (BMSDataContext db = new BMSDataContext())
                 {
                     this.Delete(db, ref validationErrors, userAccountId);
                     if (validationErrors.Count == 0)
                     {
                         //Commit transaction since the delete was successful
                         ts.Complete();
                         return true;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         return false;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             throw new Exception("DBAction not delete.");
         }
     }
```

The error occurs on the second "using statement". It says **'BMS_DAL.BMSDataContext type used in using statement must be implicitly convertible to "System.IDisposable"'**.

What must be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The error specifies that `BMSDataContext` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, and `using` statements require types that do.

Take out the second `using` statement, and replace it with the `new`.

Or, you can implement `IDisposable` on `BMSDataContext` if it's needed.  You can read [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492984/1210520) that might help you decide if you need to implement it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the System.Data.Linq using Statement

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```